# FlxReplay during normal gameplay

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

I have a bunch of NPC objects in my game that are controlled via `FlxReplay` instances. and they are preventing me from using the mouse and keyboard to control the hero directly. Is there a way to play the next frame of the `FlxReplay`, read the inputs and then revert the input to what they were before?

Example:

```
package com.geokureli.testbed;

import flixel.FlxG;
import flixel.FlxState;
import flixel.system.replay.FlxReplay;
import flixel.ui.FlxButton;

class TestBed extends FlxState {

    var replay:FlxReplay;

    public function new() { super(); }

    override public function create():Void {
        super.create();

        replay = new FlxReplay();
        replay.load("0\n0km100,100,0,0\n100km178,240,2,0\n101km178,240,1,0\n102km178,240,-1,0\n103km178,240,0,0\n");

        add(new FlxButton(50, 30, "test", function(){ trace("click"); }));
    }

    override public function update(elapsed:Float):Void {

        if (replay != null) {

            replay.playNextFrame();

            if (FlxG.mouse.justPressed)
                trace("replay click");

            if (replay.finished) {

                replay = null;
                trace("done");
            }
        }

        // --- REVERT INPUTS HERE

        super.update(elapsed);
    }
}
```

I'm unable to click the button while the replay is active. I'm wondering if I could swap out the `FlxG.inputs` and `FlxG.keys`/`mouse` during all of the replays and then swap back the originals after. Or if I can target specific inputs for the replay to use, leaving the main player's inputs unaffected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have done something like this for Ludum Dare 38.
I separated the replay from its dependency to `FlxG` controls.
Check the `MyReplay` class:

https://github.com/boorik/Ludum38/blob/master/source/MyReplay.hx

This way I can interact with the game without interfering with NPC replays.
In my game you play with all the characters of the game to record their replay. While recording one replay, other recorded replays are played on their target NPC.

You can have a look to the result here:

http://games.boorik.com/ludumdare38/

I hope I have understood your issue and this helps.

Comment: yep, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. In order to try this I had to bypass FlxMouse's private constructor but it's working.